# Prolog - How to set timestamp as an argument in a predicate?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Is there any way to use get_time(T) [which is built-in function] as an argument when I assert new facts to DB?
(I just want to compare between facts assertion time).

## Code:

```
:- dynamic start/2.
    
start_interval(A) :- start(A, _), !, false.
start_interval(A) :- assert(start(A, get_time(T))).
```

## Run Example:

```
Warning: c:/users/*****/desktop/prolog/4.pl:6:
Warning:    Singleton variables: [T]
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.2.1)
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software.
Please run ?- license. For legal details.

For online help and background, visit https://www.swi-prolog.org
For built-in help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

?- start_interval(1).
true.

?- start_interval(2).
true.

?- listing(start).
:- dynamic start/2.

start(1, get_time(_)).
start(2, get_time(_)).

true.

?- get_time(T).
T = 1598718310.038124.
```

Instead of "start(#, get_time(_))", I would like to get to timestamp, which was made when I called start_interval(Num) at first.
(You can see also the output of get_time(T) when I call it)

Is it possible?
Maybe there is another way to compare between facts assertion time?

Comment: This was double posted at [SWI-Prolog forum](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/how-to-set-timestamp-as-an-argument-in-a-predicate/2846?u=ericgt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to actually call (whatever is behind) the `get_time(T)` expression (nominally a predicate, but not really, as its behaviour depends on the *exact moment at which it is called*. Very non-logical: we are in the real of I/O).

As you write it, it remains an un-called syntactic element, standing *literally* for itself.

(Also, use `assertz/1` in preference to the oldish `assert/1`):

So:

```
:- dynamic start/2.

start_interval(A) :- start(A, _), !, false.
start_interval(A) :- get_time(T), assertz(start(A, T)).
```

Then:

```
?- start_interval(1).
true.

?- start(A,T).
A = 1,
T = 1598726506.9420764.
```